My Coverage Tool in Intellij is giving me weird results
I have been trying to do a Coverage Test on my Scala code and it doesn't seem to want to work correctly
My Code:
case class Play(
                 customerId: String,
                 forename: String,
                 surname: String
               )


Test Case:
class PlayTest extends AnyFunSuite {
  test("Test Play case class") {
    val customer = Play("1", "Alice", "Smith")
    assert(customer.customerId == "1")
    assert(customer.forename == "Alice")
    assert(customer.surname == "Smith")
  }
}


My Coverage:
Class, %: 50% (1/2)
Method, %: 80% (4/5)
Line, %: 80% (4/5)

As you can see, my Play(...) is return that it has read 1 line out of 2 and apparent I have covered 4/5 lines in my test. I only have what is in My Code in my Play file.
I just want to know where the 2 is coming from and how I can test for it so I can get a coverage of 100%.

I guess this just for the sake of demonstrating the issue but in cas it is not, keep in mind that there's very little value in testing this and even more in checking coverage of these lines.

IDEA's built-in code coverage engine only works well with Java, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2024.1/code-coverage.html#-woaesr_23 . For Scala, I suggest using https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-scoverage-code-analysis instead.
